# Specify a range of numbers in PHP's imap_mail_move function

Tags: php, imap

I esentially want to accomplish the following

```
imap_mail_move($imapStream, imap_num_msg($imapStream), "INBOX.Parsed");
imap_expunge($imapStream);
```

but that only will move the first message, the function apparantly needs a range to work properly. Problem is the only example on the php documentation page is as follows

```
imap_mail_copy($mbox,'16','[Gmail]/Starred'); // 16 is the message number, which can also be a range.(ex: '1:15')
```

If I try to use the sytax 1:15 or 1:imap_num_msg($imapStream) it results in the following error

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':'
```

How can I move the total count of my messages in my inbox to a different folder and properly specify that range?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It needs to be a string type in PHP.

```
$var = 1:15;
```

Is not valid PHP syntax. You need to do:

```
$var = '1:15';
```

Try this line instead:

```
imap_mail_copy($mbox, '1:'.imap_num_msg($imapStream), '[Gmail]/Starred');
```